Pop to Root in Jetpack Compose
If I log the NavController's back stack, I notice the root entry has a NavDestination.id of 0x0.  Is it bad practice/is there a better documented way of popping to root other than merely saying
navOptions {
    popUpTo(0)
}


Referencing Jetpack Compose clear back stack, popUpTo/popBackStack inclusive explained, "Clear back stack":

you are able to access the NavHostController’s graph and its id.
navController.navigate("login") {
    popUpTo(navController.graph.id) {
        inclusive = true
    }
}


I do indeed find this is 0x0 in my case, and works as intended.
